# What is difference between process and progress?

Tags: differences

What is difference between process and progress.
Does progress mean how many percent completed of process ?
Best regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is quite true. Especially in the computer field.

According to the dictionary:

1. *Process* means 'a series of actions or steps taken in order to achieve a particular end'.
2. *Progress* means 'forward or onward movement towards a destination'.

When we talk about *process*, we usually concern the actions or steps taken. (e.g. *The manufacturing process is relatively simple.*)

When we talk about *progress*, we usually place particular emphasize on the destination or goal. (e.g. *We are making progress toward equal rights.*)

Answer (score 0):

**Process:-**
 A series of operations performed in the making or treatment of a product: Like "coffee making process".. Typically it involves the following steps (1.light the stove, 2.place the vessel , 3.Put 100ml water, 4.add coffee-powder+milk+sugar, 5.once it reached boiling point  etc...)

@ Does progress mean how many percent completed of process?
Almost ur right..(It can also be used to mention the time taken for the process)

**Progress:-**
The process of time; 
1. lighting vessel is in progress.
2. Placing the vessel is in progress.
3. Adding Milk,Sugar,Coffee powder is in progress.
4. Boiling is in progress.
etc...

On the whole you can say coffee preparation is in progress...
(After progress u may get Success or failure or nil)